# Create a subdomain and a CNAME in Azure

Tags: azure, cname

I currently have an Azure domain with a website, the domain has the name aaa-aaa.azurewebsites.net

I need to create a subdomain of the style login.aaa-aaa-aaa.azurewebsites.net, which at first will point to aaa-aaa.azurewebsites.net but later I want it to point to a different domain.

I have tried to create the subdomain through the Azure console, entering App Service and then Custom Domains but I get the error:

"Domain ownership
To verify domain ownership create CNAME and TXT record with your DNS provider using the configuration below, and replace {subdomain} with value of subdomain".

I have been reviewing documentation on the internet and in the DNS zone section I have created a new zone and I have introduced the information that appears in the Custom Domains section as the guide says: https://rmiravalles.com/2020/08/05/creating-dns-records-for-a-web-app/

** What should I do to create this subdomain and its corresponding CNAME in Azure?

** Is it necessary to have a domain of the style aaa.com or could it be done with the one I currently have aaa-aaa.azurewebsites.net?

Thank you very much

[1]: Error creating subdomain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ9Iz.png
[2]: DNSZone configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fanN3.png

Answer (score 0):

You do not own 'azurewebsites.net' (microsoft does) and therefor you can not create subdomains for that domain (others than the ones Microsoft has given to you). You should get your own domain first, than you can create dubdomains in your dns-server